# Ubuntu not recognizing serial ports

Tags: 16.04

Since upgrading to 16.04, Ubuntu does not recognize any serial ports. This limits my options, since my computer's only internet connection is via a usb dongle. How can I convince Ubuntu to recognize the serial ports when I am unable to connect
 to the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By serial ports, I think you mean USB ports, yes? Your USB dongle probably requires a driver to make it work. Since 16.04, Ubuntu now requires that all drivers be signed, to show that they're authentic and approved. Your driver probably isn't signed. So the driver won't load.

To make your USB dongle work again, turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You are correct, I meant USB not serial ports. I disabled "secure virtual machine mode" in the BIOS setup - Ubuntu appears to be running fine now.

Comment: I guess I'm fated to be "that guy".

Comment: You lost me....

Comment: I guess the rest of my comment was eaten. Ubuntu updated and now does not open at all. Dropping back to "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-67 generic" opens OK but no USB. Not sure if it's an issue but my system is dual boot Ubuntu/Windows. Ubuntu is default and the Windows side appears to function correctly.

Comment: Recheck your BIOS and make sure that "secure virtual machine mode" is the only thing related to "secure boot". You may have to play with that if you do find another/different setting. Some Ubuntu update may have gone wrong. Open another question and describe in whatever detail you can what messages you see, or any other details.